# Postman Responds 200 but my app doesn't [ERROR 403] Swift

Tags: swift, api, postman, alamofire, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to consume my server using a local IP and If I try an auth using Postman I get data but If I use my application it doesn't. I don't know what's going on?

API URL

[image: API URL]

RESPONSE

[image]

APP RESPONSE
[image: APP RESPONSE]

and I'm consuming the following url in my app:

"http://192.168.0.19:81/api/Auth/login/movil"

This is how I make my request

```
 func login(user: User, completionHandler: @escaping (UserP?)->Void){
        var userData: UserP! = nil
        AF.request(UserRouter.login(user: user)).responseJSON{ response in
            print(user.Username)
            print(user.Password)
            switch(response.result){
            case .success(let response):
                print(response)
                let dict = (response as? [String : Any])!
                if let json = dict["data"] as? [String: Any] {

                    if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json , options: .prettyPrinted)
                    {
                        do {
                            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                            print(jsonString)
                            userData = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserP.self, from: jsonData)
                            print("Object Converted:")
                        } catch {
                            print("Parsing Failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    print("Credenciales Incorrectas")
                }
                completionHandler(userData)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(userData)
            }
        }
    }
```

ROUTER

```
 enum UserRouter : APIConfiguration {

     // MARK: -API Configuration
     case login(user: User)
     case create(user: User)
     case update(user: User)
     case getById(id: Int)
     case get
     case delete(id: Int)

     // MARK: -HTTP Methods
     var method: HTTPMethod {
         switch self {
         case .login, .create:
                 return .post
             case .update:
                 return .put
             case .delete:
                 return .delete
             case .get, .getById:
                 return .get
         }
     }

     // MARK: -API Endpoints
     var path: String {
         switch self {
             case .login:
                 return "Auth/login/movil"
             case .create:
                 return "/usuario"
             case .update:
                 return "/usuario"
             case .delete:
                 return "/usuario"
             case .get:
                 return "/usuario"
             case .getById(let id):
                 return "/usuario/\(id)"
         }
     }

     // MARK: -Parameters
     var parameters: RequestParams {
         switch self {
             case .login(let user):
                 return .body(["usuario": user.Name, "password": user.Password])
             case .create(let user):
                 return .body(["user": user])
             case .update(let user):
                 return .body(["user": user])
             case .delete(let id):
                 return .body(["id": id])
             case .get:
                 return .body([:])
             case .getById:
                 return .body([:])
         }
     }

     // MARK: URLRequest
     func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
         let url = try Constants.Production.apiURL.asURL()

         var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))

         urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

         urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeadersField.acceptType.rawValue)
         urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeadersField.contentType.rawValue)
         urlRequest.setValue(Constants.Production.authenticationToken, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeadersField.authentication.rawValue)

         switch parameters {
             case .body(let parameters):
                 urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
             case .url(let parameters):
                 let queryParameters = parameters.map { pair in
                     return URLQueryItem(name: pair.key, value: "\(pair.value)")
                 }
                 var components = URLComponents(string: url.appendingPathComponent(path).absoluteString)
                 components?.queryItems = queryParameters
                 urlRequest.url = components?.url
         }

         return urlRequest
     }
 }
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to show the code referencing your problem

Comment: The code works fine, the response not. I don't know if I need permissions or something like that

Comment: How are you building your request object? Did you add the necessary headers? If the request is not built correctly the response could be soo... so check your request object

Comment: I'll update the post

Answer (score 0):

I CHANGED `user.Name` to `user.Username`

ERROR

```
 var parameters: RequestParams {
         switch self {
             case .login(let user):
                 return .body(["usuario": user.Name, "password": user.Password])
         }
     }
```

FIXED

```
 var parameters: RequestParams {
         switch self {
             case .login(let user):
                 return .body(["usuario": user.Username, "password": user.Password])
         }
     }
```